# AlpineJS can't get checkbox values

Tags: php, codeigniter-4, alpine.js

I am creating my very first project with AlpineJS and i can't figure out how to get values from checkbox'es... text inputs and radio buttons work just fine, no problem at all.

```
<div x-data="{'loan_begin':'','loan_end':'','category':'','status':'','restricted_adverse_claims':'1','interest_by_law':'1','fk_borrower_id':'7'}">
            
            <div class="row">
                
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    
                    <h2 class="h2">Staatus</h2>
                            
                    <div class="statuses-wrapper">
                    
                                        
                        <div class="input-wrapper">
                            <input type="radio" name="loan[status]" x-model="status" value="1" id="status-1">
                            <label for="status-1">foo</label>
                        </div>
                        
                                        
                        <div class="input-wrapper">
                            <input type="radio" name="loan[status]" x-model="status" value="2" id="status-2">
                            <label for="status-2">foo</label>
                        </div>
                        
                                        
                        <div class="input-wrapper">
                            <input type="radio" name="loan[status]" x-model="status" value="3" id="status-3">
                            <label for="status-3">foo</label>
                        </div>
                        
                                        
                        <div class="input-wrapper">
                            <input type="radio" name="loan[status]" x-model="status" value="4" id="status-4">
                            <label for="status-4">foo</label>
                        </div>
                        
                                        
                        <div class="input-wrapper">
                            <input type="radio" name="loan[status]" x-model="status" value="5" id="status-5">
                            <label for="status-5">foo</label>
                        </div>
                        
                                        
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    
                    <h2 class="h2">Periood</h2>
                    
                    <div class="input-wrapper">
                        <label for="loan_begin">Alguskuupäev</label>
                        <input type="text" id="loan_begin" name="loan[loan_begin]" x-model="loan_begin">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="input-wrapper">
                        <label for="loan_end">Lõppkuupäev</label>
                        <input type="text" id="loan_end" name="loan[loan_end]" x-model="loan_end">
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="col-md-12 restrictions-wrapper">
                    
                    <div class="row">
                        
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            
                            <h2 class="h2">Piirangud</h2>
                            
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            
                            <div class="input-wrapper" style="margin-top: 12px;">
                                <input type="hidden" name="loan[restricted_adverse_claims]" value="0">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="restricted_adverse_claims" name="loan[restricted_adverse_claims]" value="1">
                                
                                <span x-text="restricted_adverse_claims">1</span>
                                
                                <label for="restricted_adverse_claims">bar</label>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            
                            <div class="input-wrapper" style="margin-top: 12px;">
                                <input type="hidden" name="loan[interest_by_law]" value="0">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="interest_by_law" name="loan[interest_by_law]" value="1">
                                
                                <span x-text="interest_by_law">1</span>
                                
                                <label for="interest_by_law">bar</label>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                    
                </div>        
                
            </div>
            
        </div>
```

If i remove x-model attribute from HTML, then i can get the checkbox values.
If i add them back, then both checkboxes will always return `string(0)`

This is also the reason why the checkbox checked attribute don't work (can't get the values, with x-model attributes in checkbox element).

Thank you for any help!

Comment: It turns out that the value in x-data for checkbox needs to be true or false, not 0 or 1